# How to JSON parsing to GoogleSignInAccount data at flutter dart

Tags: json, object, dart, flutter, google-signin

I want to get JSON data from GoogleSignInAccount.

```
_googleSignIn.onCurrentUserChanged.listen((GoogleSignInAccount account) async {
  if (account != null) {
    auth = Auth.fromJson(json.decode(account.toString()));
    _signInView.onGoogleResponse(auth);

  } else {
    _signInView.onGoogleResponse(null);
  }
});
```

but 
account.toString() returned the response =>

```
{
 displayName: Mert TUTSAK,
 email: merttutsak@gmail.com
}
```

I want to return the JSON object.

```
{
 "displayName": "Mert TUTSAK",
 "email": "merttutsak@gmail.com"
}
```

How to make it?

Answer (score 1):

What you get is just what `toString()` produces on a `Map`.

To get a valid JSON string, use `json.Encode()` or `jsonEncode` (they are equivalent)

```
import 'dart:convert';
...

var json = jsonEncode(account);
print(json);
```